# Html5 node graph?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, html5-canvas

Is there a `html5` version or similar to **Asterisq Roamer**?

I looked at this list of charts from Daniel Davis [list](http://my.opera.com/tagawa/blog/list-of-javascript-charting-libraries), but can't find any that has:

1. Loading data from xml(better json)
2. Minimum level of connections 2
3. Animated custom boxes

This is [Asterisq](http://asterisq.com/products/constellation/roamer/demo):

[image]

Comment: SVG is a better tool than canvas for the job.

Comment: @Shmiddty, do you have any examples of similar graph in SVG?

Comment: I'm sure you know how to use google.

Comment: @Shmiddty, sure, I can use google :-), but what is your experience with SVG graphs, what are your favourite api's?

Comment: Canvas will give better performance in general, but SVG is more flexible.  Check out vivagraph.js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several graph visualizers that I know of:

- [arbor.js](http://arborjs.org/)
- [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/)
- [d3.js](http://d3js.org/)

I think their APIs are straightforward enough that adding graphs and edges programatically based on your loaded model is easier than adapting your data to some kind of fixed schema.

Comment: tnx, Arbor looks and feels great.